# How to match on non-existence of property and not output a default value in JSON-LD framing?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, linked-data

I have a graph of [schema:ProductGroup](https://schema.org/ProductGroup) and [schema:ProductModel](https://schema.org/ProductModel) nodes, and I've written a frame to output it in a nested structure, conceptually similar to the library-book-chapter examples. Everything works, except that the framed output includes a `isVariantOf: null` on the top-level `ProductGroup`, which I'd rather not have.

```json
{
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "http://schema.org/",
    "ex": "http://example.com/"
  },
  "@id": "ex:100",
  "@type": "ProductGroup",
  "hasVariant": [...],
  "isVariantOf": null,
  "name": "All The Things"
}
```

[Full example in JSON-LD Playground](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-framed&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40vocab%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%22%2C%22ex%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%22%7D%2C%22%40graph%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22ex%3A100%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22ProductGroup%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22All%20The%20Things%22%2C%22hasVariant%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22ex%3A110%22%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22ex%3A120%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22ex%3A110%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22ProductGroup%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Some%20Things%22%2C%22hasVariant%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22ex%3A111%22%7D%5D%2C%22isVariantOf%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22ex%3A100%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22ex%3A111%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22ProductGroup%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Some%20Finer%20Things%22%2C%22hasVariant%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22ex%3Athing1%22%7D%5D%2C%22isVariantOf%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22ex%3A110%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22ex%3A120%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22ProductGroup%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Some%20Other%20Things%22%2C%22hasVariant%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22ex%3Athing2%22%7D%5D%2C%22isVariantOf%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22ex%3A100%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22ex%3Athing1%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22ProductModel%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Thing%201%22%2C%22isVariantOf%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22ex%3A111%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22ex%3Athing2%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22ProductModel%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Thing%202%22%2C%22isVariantOf%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22ex%3A120%22%7D%7D%5D%7D&frame=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40vocab%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%22%2C%22ex%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%22%7D%2C%22%40graph%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22ProductGroup%22%2C%22%40requireAll%22%3Atrue%2C%22isVariantOf%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%7D) (toggle between something like Flattened and Framed to get it to output correctly).

The top-level `ProductGroup` doesn't have an `isVariantOf` property. In my framing document, I'm matching on this being empty. But, I can't figure out how to omit the empty `isVariantOf` property in the output. I think I have to set the `@omitDefault` flag, but I'm having trouble figuring out where or how.

```json
{
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "http://schema.org/",
    "ex": "http://example.com/"
  },
  "@graph": {
    "@type": "ProductGroup",
    "@requireAll": true,
    "isVariantOf": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [Framing Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11-framing/#match-on-the-absence-of-a-property), using the **Match on the Absence of a Property** mechanism explicitly adds a property with `null` to the output to indicate that the property does not exist. To remove it, you can re-compact the results using the frame as a context, as the Expansion Algorithm removes all properties with null values.